# Expo - scheduled notification. Bring app to foreground

Tags: react-native, expo

I have been searching through the Expo documentation and haven't been able to find anything.

Is it possible to bring an app to the foreground using expo?

e.g. if I made a simple alarm clock - would it be possible to bring the app to the foreground and show an alarm screen without actively clicking on a notification?

I'm interested in both iOS and Android - any information is very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying the app should run automatically?

Comment: Just like when someone calls on Skype or whatsapp.

Comment: I'm looking for same behavior. I have set priorities for notifications in my app, i am sending them in "data". Requirement is, if(data.priority == "high") bringAppInForeground;
Is that possible??

Comment: Have there been any updates/breakthroughs on this yet? In 2022 I'm still struggling with this.... Maybe it has something to do with Deep Linking within Expo/React Navigation... Testing in the Expo Go App doesn't seem to do the trick